# Unable to play video in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a video player using angular js. I am not able to play the video. Below is what i tried.

```
    videoPlayer.factory('controloptions',function()
{
    var controloptions={};
    controloptions.state="play";
    controloptions.volumestate="high";
    controloptions.videoElement=angular.element(document.querySelector("#video_play"))

    controloptions.play1=function($event)
    {
        angular.element(document.querySelector("#video_play")).play(); 
        alert("a")
    },
    controloptions.pause1=function($event)
    {

        console.log(controloptions.videoElement)
        //controloptions.state="pause";
        angular.element(document.querySelector("#video_play")).pause(); 
    }
   }
```

I dont know whether this is rigth way to play a video.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular.element creates a jquery/jqlite element, which has [a very specific set of methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). play() is not one of them.

```
document.querySelector("#video_play").play(); // Works
angular.element(document.querySelector("#video_play"))[0].play(); // Works as well
```

It is kind of pointless to create a jquery-object unless you at the very least save it away for later use.

But is it the *angular way™*? Maybe. You could bake the mess in a directive and hide it out of sight, but you have to call the html-element at some point.

```
// Perhaps something along those lines to make it look cleaner.
$scope.video = $element.find('video')[0];
$scope.video.play();
```